# node.js, need help to fix this bug "TypeError: object is not a function"

Tags: node.js

I am learning node.js. trying some demos on cloud9.  the demo is very simple, only 2 js files. I checked line by line, everything seems fine. please help me to debug it.

1. resource.js file.

   ```
           var util = require('util');
           var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

           function Resource(m){

               var maxEvents = m;
               var self = this;

               process.nextTick(function(){
                   var count = 0;

                   self.emit('start');
                   var t = setInterval(function(){
                       self.emit('data', ++count);

                       if(count === maxEvents){
                           self.emit('end', count);
                           clearInterval(t);
                       }
                   }, 10);
               });

           };

           util.inherits(Resource, EventEmitter);
   ```
2. 7-extEmitter.js

   ```
           var Resource = require('./resource');


           var r = new Resource(7);


           r.on('start', function(){
               console.log("I've started!");
           });

           r.on('data', function(d){
               console.log("    I received data -> " + d);
           });

           r.on('end', function(t){
               console.log("I'm done, with " + t + " data events.");
           });
   ```

here's the error message I got:

```
            Your code is running at 'http://node.myw714.c9.io'.
            Important: use 'process.env.PORT' as the port and 'process.env.IP' as the host in your scripts!
            /var/lib/stickshift/511e07b5500446f25c0001bd/app-root/data/407149/7-extEmitter.js:4
            var r = new Resource(7);

              ^
            TypeError: object is not a function
                at Object. (/var/lib/stickshift/511e07b5500446f25c0001bd/app-root/data/407149/7-extEmitter.js:4:9)
                at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
                at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
                at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
                at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
                at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
                at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove that initialization code.

```
    var r = require('./resource');


    r.on('start', function(){
        console.log("I've started!");
    });

    r.on('data', function(d){
        console.log("    I received data -> " + d);
    });

    r.on('end', function(t){
        console.log("I'm done, with " + t + " data events.");
    });
```

And add this line in the resource.js, if you want it to be more general, you should change the function structure to allow to set the value m.

```
module.exports = new Resource(7);
```

Answer (score 0):

Under the utils.inherit in the resource.js file you just need to add this:

```
module.exports = Resource;
```

The rest of the code is fine.